# Python 3 IOError on renaming files

Tags: python, rename, ioerror

I'm writing a script that parses some directories to rename files with special characters. My code looks like this:

```
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(mountpunt):
for fl in files:
    #pdb.set_trace()      
    print(fl)                    
    validfl = get_valid_filename(fl)
    print( validfl )
    if validfl != fl:
        try:
            os.rename(fl,validfl)
            print("renamed " + fl + " to " + validfl)
        except (UnicodeEncodeError) as e:
            print("unicode error")
            errors += 1
            pass
        except (IOError) as ex:
            print("IO error on " + fl)
            errors += 1
            pass
```

I have files that are named like 1000(1).jpg,1000(2).jpg etc.
 On trying to rename these files to 10001.jpg,10002.jpg etc. I get an IO error. I'm working on Ubuntu and I am able to open these files in an image viewer. What should I do to solve this IO error?

Regards,

When I run the script this is the output:

006_1000(2).jpg
006_10002.jpg
IO error on 006_1000(2).jpg
006_1000(1).jpg
006_10001.jpg
IO error on 006_1000(1).jpg
.directory
.directory
006_1000(3).jpg
006_10003.jpg
IO error on 006_1000(3).jpg
007_1000.jpg
007_1000.jpg

As you see the file gets renamed correctly.
This is the code for get_valid_filename():

```
def get_valid_filename(s):
    s = str(s).strip().replace(' ', '_')
    return re.sub(r'(?u)[^-\w.]', '', s)
```

Comment: post complete error

Comment: and also `get_valid_filename`.

Comment: how do I post this? By 'Answer Your Question'?

Comment: found it (it was by editing my message).

Comment: Your code is searching in a directory that might be anywhere on the disk, and recursively searches in subdirectories - yet you are calling `os.rename()` on the *filenames alone*, which will only work if they happen to be in the current directory.  You need to use `os.path.join(root, fl)` (and similarly for `validfl`) to get the full pathname of the file.

Comment: You should also print the exception in your exception handling (like `print(ex)`), because it'll give you valuable information what went wrong.

Comment: Or add a simple `raise` to your except block to reraise the exception and see the traceback.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this to me. The answer of Jason solved the problem. It's good to know how to get more out of exceptions.